# CSS overflowing even with overflow-x: hidden on html element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I want to have some graphics "peeking" from the edges of the page. The graphics are SVGs, and the invisible part should be "cut off" from the edge of the screen

I tried to setup up a generic class `.graphic` with the position of `relative`. I load the SVG as the `content` of the `.graphic::before`. The `::before` has `absolute` position and I try to use `inset` to place it on the edge of the screen. This causes the horizontal scrolling to appear, which is something I don't want. Note that this appears to be working properly on the desktop, but if you open it in the responsive mode, and use any mobile view, you will notice the horizontal scrol.

I tried to put the `overflow-x: hidden` on the `html` element, but it doesn't help.
Does someone know how to achieve this?

You can see the minimal example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-naovyb?file=src/style.css

What is interesting in the above example, is that the left graphic alone doesn't cause the overflow. As soon as I add the right one, the overflow appears. What is the reason for this?

Comment: "I load the SVG as the `content: url('/vite.svg');` of the `.graphic::before`" - why are you doing that instead of using `background-image:` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce any horizontal scrolling in mobile-device emulation in DevTools in Chrome 112,

Comment: Strange you can’t repro it, I see it the real mobile device as well as in the emulation. If I were to use background image,would it make any difference?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }` solves your problem